# Chart format option not available for Excel web app

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have a subscription of Office Home and Student 2016.

When I upload my excel file with a chart to Excel web app, I am unable to see the 'Format' option for the chart. Please see the snapshot below.

[Without 'Format' option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlM6T.png)

I experimented around a bit and in the process I created a new account at outlook.live.com, I then uploaded the Excel file to the Excel web app for that account, I was able to see the option. Please see the snapshot below.

[With 'Format' option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsdDk.png)

There is one difference between these two accounts: The new account I created had 'USA' as the country.

Please help if I am missing some options to enable.